# Is it possible to Pick Multiple Users from AddressBook

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, addressbookui

I am trying to select Multiple Users from AddressBook.Is it possible ? 
As far as i checked. In `ABPeoplePickerNavigationController` it is possible to select 1 user at a time from AddressBook.Likewise is it possible to pick Multiple Users from AddressBook.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are couple of sample projects that you can use that do exactly what you are looking for

[TKContactsMultiPicker for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/tkcontactsmultipicker)

[MultiContactsSelector for iOS](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/multicontactsselector)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the People Picker `delegate` has the following:

`peoplePickerNavigationController:shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson`:

Which, if you `return NO`, you can perform logic (queue up info, perform an animation, etc) and then continue displaying the picker until all people are picked from the picker....

Comment: Thanks.. any tutorials or sample code based on using this logic?

Comment: API mentioned is deprecated in 8.0